# Scalar equation including $\ell_1$ norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

My problem is very simple: is there an analytic solution to
$$
\mbox{find  } \alpha  \mbox{ such that } \|u + \alpha v\|_1 = \beta 
$$

Here $u$, $v$, and $\beta$ are known quantities.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: I assume $\alpha$ is a scalar. Are $u,v$ vectors in $\Bbb R^n$? If yes what is $n$? If $v=0$ it might be impossible. If $||u||_1 > \beta$ it is impossible too due to the triangle inequality.

Comment: @flawr it is not impossible for $||u||_1>\beta$, you used the triangle inequality backwards: take for instance the case $u,v$ parallel, then there exists $\alpha$ such that the norm vanishes.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks!

Comment: Yes sorry $u$ and $v$ are vector of $\mathbb R^n$, with $n$ unknown. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are scalar.
I actually found the solution with its existence condition if $\|u\|_1 > \beta$. The case  $\|u\|_1 <\beta$ seems more tricky. So if you have any Idea I would be grateful !

Comment: With $\alpha=0$ we have $||u+\alpha v||_1<\beta$. Assuming $v\neq0$ we know that $ ||u+\alpha v ||_1 \to + \infty$ for $\alpha \to \pm \infty$. Because $\alpha \mapsto ||u+\alpha v||_1$ is continuous there must be an $\alpha$ such that $||u+\alpha v ||_1 = \beta$, which proves the existence, but I do not know if you can actually construct it.

Answer (score 0):

This contribution was meant to be a remark but was to long for a comment.

The solution may not be so simple as can be seen from a special case. We have

$$
\parallel u+\alpha v\parallel _{1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}|u_{j}+\alpha v_{j}|
$$
Consider the special case
\begin{eqnarray*}
v &=&(v_{1},0,\cdots 0),\;v_{1}\neq 0 \\
u &=&(u_{1},u_{2},\cdots 0),\;u_{1},u_{2}\neq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
&\parallel &u+\alpha v\parallel _{1}=|u_{1}+\alpha v_{1}|+|u_{2}|=\beta
\geqslant 0 \\
|u_{1}+\alpha v_{1}| &=&\beta -|u_{2}|\geqslant 0
\end{eqnarray*}
We see that there is no solution for $\alpha $ if $\beta <|u_{2}|$, whatever
$u_{1}$. Since $u_{2}$ is given and if we have
$$
\beta -|u_{2}|=\gamma >0
$$
then we have to find $\alpha $ such that
$$
|u_{1}+\alpha v_{1}|=\gamma
$$
Now
\begin{eqnarray*}
u_{1}+\alpha v_{1} &=&\gamma \Rightarrow \alpha =\frac{\gamma -u_{1}}{v_{1}}%
,\;u_{1}+\alpha v_{1}>0 \\
-u_{1}-\alpha v_{1} &=&\gamma \Rightarrow \alpha =-\frac{\gamma +u_{1}}{v_{1}%
},\;u_{1}+\alpha v_{1}<0
\end{eqnarray*}
$\textbf{Remark:}$ In the $l^{2}$-case the situation is simpler for then the
special case can be achieved by employing a rotation which leaves the norm
invariant.